# How to choose the paper size in LibreOffice?

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

Is it possible to set your page size to A3 or A1 as in Microsoft Word in LibreOffice? Or any way to choose a custom page size in LibreOffice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click on Format --> page, and you can get it done that way.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is better than the answer in "Ask LiberOffice" website.